# Clickable But Not Visible?

Tags: protractor

I am fairly new to Protractor E2E testing and was wondering if it was possible for an element to be clickable (`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`) but not necessarily visible (`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf`).

For example, I have the following code:

```
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var tryItButtonClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(tryItButton);
    var tryItButtonVisible = EC.visibilityOf(tryItButton);

    return browser.wait(EC.and(tryItButtonClickable, tryItButtonVisible), getWaitTime())
        .then(function() {
             var protocol = url.parse(myarray[0].url).protocol;
                 if (protocol === null) {
                     throw new Error('expected ' + protocol + ' not to be null');
                 }
        })
```

Before adding the `tryItButtonVisible` piece, I would receive a time out error from Protractor, presumably because my `tryItButton` was clickable but hadn't been loaded into the DOM.

Is this true, or am I being redundant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is offical  clickable function of protractor

```
elementToBeClickable(elementFinder: ElementFinder): Function {
return this.and(this.visibilityOf(elementFinder), () => {
  return elementFinder.isEnabled().then(passBoolean, falseIfMissing);
})
```

as you see, it checks element visibility first so answer is NO

resource:https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/expectedConditions.ts line:188

Comment: I'm just curious then as to why when I `and` both conditions together, the behavior is the expected one whereas when I only use `elementToBeClickable` my UI freezes and can't find the element